# structure module and classic subdomains

Tags: structure, htaccess, subdomain

We have a site originally written in ee 1.5.2 using the classic subdomain method. Can I take  "classic" subdomain folders and move them into subfolders in Structure for organizational purposes and then use .htaccess to get them to show as subdomains in the browser when they are rendered?

Thank you in advance. . . to the remarkable ee se braintrust!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your thinking but I can't see it working.

As Travis says, the parent entries (for example /about) there's no way you could create a subfolder on the server of /about - as soon as you do that, it'll take precedence.

As for the htaccess route, the browser will try route it to an actual subdomain and would fail if not found.

Comment: Thank you for your expertise.  Will simply migrate the original architecture of that site so subdomains remain outside of Structure.